# Can anyone help me install a Custom OS on this old tablet?

Tags: custom-roms, tablet, lg, att

I have an [LG G Pad™ 7.0 LTE](https://www.lg.com/us/tablets/lg-V410-g-pad-7.0-lte) that I got as a gift and I want to install a Custom Rom such as LineageOS on it.  The only problem is that I do not know how to do this on a somewhat old tablet such as this. The tablet in question is:

1. [This is a LG G Pad™](https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_g_pad_7_0_lte-6554.php) [7.0 LTE](https://www.cnet.com/reviews/lg-g-pad-7-0-review/) that used to be from AT&T.
2. The operating system is an Android 5.0.2 or Lollipop.

I was following the instructions on how to install the Custom Rom but I struggle with rooting portion of it. The recommended rooting programs such as Kingaroot or iRoot have failed and I think bricked my tablet. I am looking fomr more hlp with this. Can anyone help with rooting my tablet?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/f/lg-g-pad-7-roms-kernels-recoveries-other-deve.9004

Comment: That site did help me out. I still need to install the OS and Root it though.

Comment: It seems as though that LG phones are the hardest to mod for.

Comment: choose some stable ROM, follow the tutorial, post link and tell us which step failed for you (kindly edit your question)

Comment: I was able to find the problem with some help from the Android OS reddit.